# Need help resolving NoMethod Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

I need help resolving an error. I have been researching this for a while now and just can't seem to figure out how to fix this. Thanks in advance for any assistance. The goal is to update the field 'industry' in my reviewers table.

The error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for #<Reviewer:0x007fee8dbb3f40>)
```

The code where this error is contained in my `reviewers_controller` where I set the controller:

```
def set_reviewer
  @reviewer = current_user.reviewer.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is the update method:

```
  def update
    if @reviewer.update(reviewer_params)
      render json: @reviewer
    else
      render json: @reviewer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Here are my models:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reviewer
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Authentication
  has_one :reviewer
  has_many :reviews, through: :reviewer
end

class Reviewer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In `set_reviewer` I tried `.find_by` and that did not work. I have read the documentation on the `has_one` macro and `.find()`, but am just spinning my wheels. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: `through` must make reference to another model, a third model, do you have a model called `reviewers`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma,
Thanks for a taking a look. That was an error. I have updated my original post with models. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the reviewer by doing this:

```
@reviewer = current_user.reviewer
```

`current_user.reviewer` will return the associated reviewer object. You're getting this error because you're trying to call find on the reviewer object itself.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You're very welcome! Please accept this answer if it helped you.